# Script returning undefined property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to the File and FileReader API's that HTML5 introduced and I'm having an issue with reading the actual file.  In the HTML I have the user selecting the file using an input field.  I'm passing the DOM element into a variable, and when the user hits a load button, I'm checking the file.  However, I'm getting the following error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined`

So apparently, the entire thing is coming back as undefined, I'm not sure why it is, or if I'm even doing the check right, but here's my code.  Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div id="uploadFile">
    <span>DAT File: </span><input type="file" id="selectedFile">
    <div id="loadButtons">
        <button id="load">Load</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var selectedFile = $("#selectedFile");
$("#load").on("click", function(){
    console.log(selectedFile.get(0).files[0]);
})
```

**Edit:** I've tested it in IE and it seems to be working fine, Chrome is where the issue is apparently.

Comment: Do you run JavaScript code after the DOM element has been loaded?

Comment: Then [I cannot reproduce it](http://jsbin.com/subujeqofo/1/edit?html,console,output), sorry.

Comment: Try putting `var selectedFile = $("#selectedFile");` into click callback. I don't think `selectedFile` is available at the time when you run jQuery selector.

Comment: @mostruash Still getting the same error.

Comment: @SilentTremor I do, I just don't have it included in here because it doesn't need to be.

Comment: About your edit... Your code must have something else you haven't shared. My [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/subujeqofo/1/edit?html,console,output) works in current Chrome version just fine. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, it does now.  Turns out, there was nothing actually wrong, I just needed to clear my cache.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get rid of the `get()` method you've attached to the `selectedFile` variable

```
var selectedFile = $("#selectedFile");
$("#load").on("click", function(){
    console.log(selectedFile[0].files[0]);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2ttqy5f/)

Comment: I see it working in the fiddle, but I'm still getting the same error in the application.

Comment: @Robert Did you select a file first before looking in the console?

Comment: @LloydBanks The thing is error wouldn't say `'files' of undefined` if it were the case. I think OP fails to show us something crucial in his code.

Comment: Well, I noticed that it works fine in IE, but in Chrome, it's having the issue

Comment: @mostruash I'm showing everything that has to do with this particular problem

Comment: @Robert Try clearing Chrome's history.  You might be loading an old version of your JavaScript from cache

Comment: This cannot be the answer. Your proposed fix (`[0]`) is equivalent to replaced code (`.get(0)`) -- [reference](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get-index).